# How to get data from TreeStore Extjs4.1

Tags: tree, extjs4.1

Ext JS 4.1

To get value data from 'Ext.data.Store', it simply to use

```
var data1 = store.data.items[0].data.fieldname;
```

or

```
var data1 = store.getAt(0).data.fieldname;
```

but, in 'Ext.data.TreeStore', this method is doesn't work!

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in fact a much needed functionality.

Consider the situation when you have a tree grid with a check column, you're listening to a "checkchange" event of that column and want to find a record that was just changed.

Unfortunately, all ExtJS provides you with is a record index.
Fortunately though, no one is stopping us from defining our own getAt method in our own store that does exactly what we want:

```
{
  store: 'tree',
  getAt: function (index) {
    var current = 0;
    return (function find(nodes) {
      var i, len = nodes.length;
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (current === index) {
          return nodes[i];
        }
        current++;
        var found = find(nodes[i].childNodes);
        if (found) {
          return found;
        }
      }
    }(this.tree.root.childNodes));
  }
}
```

Comment: With ExtJS 4.2.x, the node index passed via the checkchange event doesn't   count children of collapsed nodes. So with the code above I will get the wrong model record. I simply added "if (nodes[i].isExpanded()) {" ...  after "current++;" and it seems to work fine. While it seems to work, I probably won't stick with this code as it seems a bit fragile.

Answer (score 9):

This is a common misconception with Extjs.  A Ext.data.TreeStore and Ext.data.Store are actually not very similar and neither inherits from the other.

A store holds data in the format of an array of models:

```
[
    {
        attribute1,
        attribute2,
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Whereas a treestore holds data in the format of a tree structure of nodes, like this:

```
{
    attribute1,
    attribute2,
    ...,
    children: [
        {
            attribute1,
            attribute2,
            ...,
            children: [
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Due to these completely different structures underlying the regular store and treestore, the functions on them are completely different.  I'm guessing that in your example above, the correct use of store and node functions would be:

```
var data1 = treestore.getRootNode().getChildAt(0).get(fieldname);
```

`getRootNode()` gets the root node of your tree which is represented by the class `NodeInterface` which has the method `getChildAt(index)` which retrieves the first child node of the root node.  Then I use the `get(dataIndex)` function to get the property you want from the node.